# cakephp form validation displaying default message instead of custom

Tags: cakephp

Instead of my custom validation message being show upon submitting a form, the default "This field cannot be left blank" is being shown. Any ideas?

Here is my validation:

```
public $validate = array(
        'id' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'first_name' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'last_name' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'accused_of' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        ),
        'last_4_of_ssn' => array(
            'rule' => '/^[0-9]{4}$/', // NEED TO DOUBLE CHECK THIS
            'messsage' => 'Exactly 4 digits'    
        ),
        'date_of_accusation' => array(
            'rule' => array('date', 'ymd'), // NEED TO DOUBLE CHECK THIS
             'message' => 'Date must be in YYYY-MM-DD format.'
        ),
        'monitoring' => array(
            'rule' => 'notEmpty'
        )
    );
```

And here is my form:

```
echo $this->Form->create('Offender');
echo $this->Form->input('first_name', array('label' => 'First name:'));
echo $this->Form->input('last_name', array('label' => 'Last name:'));
echo $this->Form->input('accused_of', array('label' => 'Accused of:'));
echo $this->Form->input('monitoring', array('label' => 'Monitoring (enter as comma seperated list. ex: BAC, location):'));
echo $this->Form->input('last_4_of_ssn', array('label' => 'Last 4 digits of SSN:') );
echo $this->Form->input('date_of_accusation', array('label' => 'Date of accusation:'));
echo $this->Form->end('Save New Offender');
```

Comment: Which field are you referring to?

Comment: last 4 of ssn specifically.

Comment: is this `messsage` in rule `last_4_of_ssn` a typo in your code, or just happened copying the code here?

Comment: Gonna mark this as typo question then, glad it's fixed

Answer (score 0):

It appears for some fields you have not set any custom messages please go to this URL http://book.cakephp.org/2.0/en/models/data-validation.html

You can also create a custom validation for this purpose like in validation array do like this

```
   'last_4_of_ssn' => array(
        'rule' => array('digitValidate'), 
        'messsage' => 'Exactly 4 digits'    
    )
```

and in Model you can create a public function with the same name.

```
public function digitValidate() {

    $pattern = '/^[0-9]{4}$/';

   if (!preg_match($pattern,$this->data['last_4_of_ssn'])) {
      return false;
   }

  return true;

}
```

I hope this will help you.

Comment: Yeah I don't need custom messages for the majority of them (mainly for last_4_of_ssn). I checked that page out before posting and to me it looks like I have everything is okay...

Comment: don't post two answers for just a comment please

Comment: that's ok. just edit your best answer (the one you left minutes ago), add the other answer to it as an edit if you feel is useful (though it seems just like a comment and doesn't seem to really answer the question), and delete the other one.